# Activate a closed workbook, perform lRow VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been through heaps of forums and still can't understand where I'm going wrong. One of my first VBA code attempts.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
Dim ws As Long
Dim lRow As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Arr() As Variant
Dim DHSWMP As String
Dim Dams As String
Dim PotR As String

DHSWMP = "E:\Copy of PWC DHSWMP WorkSheets.xlsm"
'Dams = "x"
'PotR = "x"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(DHSWMP, True, False)
 wb.Activate

 ws = Worksheets.Count

    Do While ws > 0

        wb.Sheets(ws).Activate
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        MsgBox (lRow)
```

The code makes it through, however it is performing the lRow on the 'mastersheet' from which the macro is run and not the opened workbook. One bit that does confuse me it that the code does perform the worksheets.count on the opened workbook.

Cheers

Comment: Where is this code located (in a general Module or in a Worksheet module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs as expected for me.  This is a perfect example of why you should fully qualify your references.

To test what is going on:

- Don't turn off `ScreenUpdating`
- Improve your `MsgBox`
- Use F8 to step through the code
- Use the `Immediate Window` for additional test

> ```
>         MsgBox Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Address & vbNewLine & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Parent.Name & vbNewLine & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Parent.Parent.Name
> ```

- Cells.Parent.Name: Returns the name of the Worksheet
- Cells.Parent.Name: Returns the name of the Workbook

[image]

You should avoid the use of `Do` and `While` loops while iterating; if you know both the start and the end.  `For` and `For Each` loops wi

Here are two different ways of writing your code.  Notice that the use of `With` statements and the qualified references.  For example both the `Cells` and the `Rows` are qualified to the `Worksheet` in: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`.  This is very important to avoid any confusion on the what is the actual target of the code.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbDHSWMP As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Variant
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim DHSWMP As String, Dams As String, PotR As String

    DHSWMP = "C:\Copy of PWC DHSWMP WorkSheets.xlsm"
    Set wbDHSWMP = Workbooks.Open(DHSWMP, True, False)

    For Each ws In wbDHSWMP.Worksheets
        With ws
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            MsgBox (lRow)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Refresh_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wbDHSWMP As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Variant, n As Long
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim DHSWMP As String, Dams As String, PotR As String

    DHSWMP = "C:\Copy of PWC DHSWMP WorkSheets.xlsm"
    Set wbDHSWMP = Workbooks.Open(DHSWMP, True, False)

    For n = wbDHSWMP.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        With wbDHSWMP.Worksheets(n)
            lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            MsgBox (lRow)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow, I did not even know about the intermediate window.  And I do see my mistake now. Really appreciate the comprehensive reply.

Comment: You should watch [What to do when things go wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=3).  Thanks for accepting my answer